# How to make a ping command in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I used a couple of tricks and they don't work.
For example:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong! {0}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you actually running the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code:

```
async def ping(ctx):
    if round(client.latency * 1000) <= 50:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="PING", description=f":ping_pong: Pingpingpingpingping! The ping is **{round(client.latency *1000)}** milliseconds!", color=0x44ff44)
    elif round(client.latency * 1000) <= 100:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="PING", description=f":ping_pong: Pingpingpingpingping! The ping is **{round(client.latency *1000)}** milliseconds!", color=0xffd000)
    elif round(client.latency * 1000) <= 200:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="PING", description=f":ping_pong: Pingpingpingpingping! The ping is **{round(client.latency *1000)}** milliseconds!", color=0xff6600)
    else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="PING", description=f":ping_pong: Pingpingpingpingping! The ping is **{round(client.latency *1000)}** milliseconds!", color=0x990000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Make sure you do @client.command() at the top, I removed it because I use a different command handler. Obviously, I decided to make it fancy by color coding it, and putting everything in embeds. If you want a simple command that returns a ping, and only a ping, try this:

```
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{client.latency}")
```

It can't really get much simpler than that. If that doesn't work, try:

```
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{client.latency}")
```

As always, don't forget to add @client.command() at the top.